# C# Split JSON Array Without Deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working on developing an API that needs to filter, validate, then insert into a DB values passed from a JSON array.  This endpoint needs to be able to accept 100,000 objects at once (~30 MB).  I was thinking about developing an initial endpoint which splits the JSON array into batches for worker environments with the help of AWS SQS.  How can I split the JSON array into smaller chunks without the need to deserialize then serialize it back to JSON when being sent to SQS?  Can `jObject.SelectTokens("$[0,500]")`'s result be converted to JSON without needing to manually iterate over the results?
Calling `ToString` on the `SelectTokens` result returns `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.ArrayMultipleIndexFilter+<ExecuteFilter>d__4`

Comment: If you are planning to split the JSON array, would it be an option to instead have the callers pass you smaller payloads (e.g. 10,000 objects at once)? Why **specifically** do you want to avoid deserializing?

Comment: I can modify the caller to provide smaller payloads.  I'm just curious to see if cutting out the de/serializing steps were possible.